# Breakpoints do not break Appcelerator app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

In Appcelerator Studio I set some breakpoint in the code, but whatever I try, Appcelerator just runs the app in de emulator, without stopping.

I made a debug-configuration to run with and switched to the Debug view.

In Preferences I set Studio > Troubleshooting > Debug Level to 'All'.

In the Breakpoints-tab all breakpoints are listed and checked.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Studio > Troubleshooting > Debug Level to 'All'. You can reset this to 'Error'. This is useful to see studio debug level logs.

Do you see any debug related errors in the "Help -> Studio -> View Log". Can you share the log file.

If it's an Alloy project, do the clean the build using "Project ->Clean"

What's your environment like platform, studio version, CLI Core version and SDK version?

Comment: - MacBook Pro OSX 10.12.6. 
- CLI version 6.2.4.   
- SDK 6.2.2.GA. 
- Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.10.0.201709271713.

Comment: I did a Project > Clean, than emptied the Log File and ran the project with this result:

Comment: Euhm, don't know how to add log file content because it's to long

Comment: !ENTRY org.chromium.debug.core 1 0 2017-10-11 12:04:32.012
!MESSAGE SDK:org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection: Shutdown requested

!ENTRY org.chromium.debug.core 1 0 2017-10-11 12:05:16.178
!MESSAGE SDK:org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection: Shutdown requested

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core 4 0 2017-10-11 12:05:16.184
!MESSAGE (Build 4.10.0.201709271713) [ERROR]  Failed to get version
!STACK 0

Comment: java.io.IOException: Failed to get version
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.v8native.JavascriptVmImpl.newIOException(JavascriptVmImpl.java:101)
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.standalonev8.StandaloneVmImpl.attachImpl(StandaloneVmImpl.java:130)
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.standalonev8.StandaloneVmImpl.attach(StandaloneVmImpl.java:77)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.debug.core.V8DebugTarget.attach(V8DebugTarget.java:335)

Comment: at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidLaunchProperties.connect(AndroidLaunchProperties.java:279)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidLaunchProperties.initiateDebuggerConnection(AndroidLaunchProperties.java:254)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidLaunchProperties.access$3(AndroidLaunchProperties.java:250)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidLaunchProperties$DebuggerConnectionRunnable.run(AndroidLaunchProperties.java:387)

Comment: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: End of stream
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.standalonev8.StandaloneVmImpl.attachImpl(StandaloneVmImpl.java:125)
 ... 7 more

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: End of stream
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.Handshaker$StandaloneV8Impl$HandshakeTaks.call(Handshaker.java:122)
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.Handshaker$StandaloneV8Impl$HandshakeTaks.call(Handshaker.java:1)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.Handshaker$StandaloneV8Impl.perform(Handshaker.java:100)
 at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection$ReaderThread.run(SocketConnection.java:156)

Comment: Can you clean all the adb processes in the system and restart the debug - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-5264

Comment: Try this as well - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8782.The issue happens on a clean project only i.e. when we try to debug a project after cleaning it. However if we try to debug again without cleaning the project the debug happens successfully and breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Tag I'm assuming you're using Alloy.

In which case, these files are converted to classic files and the compiled result is positioned in the `Resources` Directory in the root of your project.

In there you'll find all your code, but slightly different as it is processed. If you set breakpoints there, and run debug mode it will work!

Comment: I opened Resources/android/alloy/controllers/index.js in Appcelerator Studio and put some breakpoints in a called function, but unfortunately, no break there. Appcelerator is overwriting it anyways on a new build, so how is this going to work?